# Flagging last overall row in MySQL query using LIMIT

Tags: php, mysql

I am retrieving results from a database in batches of 5, each time taking the last 'id' and returning it via jquery so only rows with smaller 'id' are returned. I have a load more button which should disappear after all rows are loaded, even if that means 5, 7 or 11 rows.

I have this query:

```
 $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM names WHERE id < ? ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5");
 $query->execute([$_POST["id"]]);
 while($row = $query -> fetch()) {
echo "<div id="$row["id"].">".$row["name"]."</div>";
 });
```

The question is, is there an easy and performant way to add a column to flag each row if it's last or not in a single query? Considering I am using LIMIT of 5, obviously the query should also check the potential existence of 5+1 row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the limit to 6 and check the number of returned rows.

for the while loop, use a counter:

```
$query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM names WHERE id < ? ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 6");
$query->execute([$_POST["id"]]);

$n=5;
while($row = $query -> fetch() && $n-->0) 
{
  echo "<div id="$row["id"].">".$row["name"]."</div>"; 
}
```

Comment: I need to display only 5. I am using while loop as seen above.

Comment: just break the loop after 5 entries.

Comment: what if it's only 3 entries in the db?

Comment: then the while loop will end after 3

Comment: Unfortunately I have no idea how to implement this. The last item found would have to be flagged where as the loop would break only at the next one, which does not exist.

Comment: use a counter, see modified answer

Comment: Does not work.. I get 5 results but the $row variables are empty

Comment: you say  `fetch`  does **not** return **false** even there are no more rows?

Comment: When i move $n --> 0 before the $row fetch it works. However I need to find the overall last item (outside of the LIMIT 6)... So if I have 13 entries in the database, only the 13 would get the flag "last", which means at least the iterations of sql extracts (3x5)

Comment: you can use functions like `mysqli_num_rows()` to get the total number of rows of your result. if it is 6, the last row is not part of your result. otherwise it is the last row of your current result

Comment: I already had that. If the num count is 5 or less everything was loaded, meaning i can add if check within the while loop and to the last "div" add flag "last". But in that case i need to change the order from 0 > $n instead of $n to > 0? In case it's 3 or 2 for instance?

Comment: if `num_rows()<6` , the first row is the last of your complete dataset when you use `order by id desc`.